# Print Array of Doubles to 2 Decimal Places

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of doubles and would like to print it out to the console to 2 decimal places

```
double[] ary = {12.4324324, 14.5432, 58.3412};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ary));
```

Currently this would print out

```
[12.4324324, 14.5432, 58.3412]
```

But I would instead like it to print

```
[12.43, 14.54, 58.34]
```

Is there some way I could do this with `Arrays.toString()` or would I have to iterate through every value in the array and print them individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to iterate each value to print with 2 decimal.
Using java 8 , you can do with 1 line below way.

```
    double[] ary = { 12.4324324, 14.5432, 58.3412 };
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    Arrays.stream(ary).forEach(e -> System.out.print(df.format(e) + " " ));
```

Comment: I voted for this answer because it leaves the original array intact, and provided a clean implementation of the desired formatting.

Comment: Note that this constructor will create [" a DecimalFormat using the given pattern and the symbols for the **default FORMAT locale**"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat-java.lang.String-). To get an instance that always uses a specific locale, you need to use the factory methods like [NumberFormat.getNumberInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance-java.util.Locale-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to simply implement an appropriate `toString` method with the necessary formatting options, and pass in the desired "default" format in a convenience method:

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class DoubleArrayString
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] array = { 12.4324324, 14.5432, 58.3412 };

        System.out.println(toString(array));
    }

    private static String toString(double array[])
    {
        return toString(array, Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f");
    }

    private static String toString(double array[], Locale locale, String format)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            return "null";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(String.format(locale, format, array[i]));
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

---

Note that when using `DecimalFormat`, the output will depend on the `Locale`. In Germany, the output of the currently accepted answer will be

```
12,43 14,54 58,34
```

Even if the `,` were `.`, the output would be

```
12.43 14.54 58.34
```

and not the desired (and probably expected)

```
[12.43, 14.54, 58.34]
```

Moreover, there is a difference between "printing the contents of an array to the console" and "creating a string with the contents of the array" (which may then be printed to the console). The method shown above is a building block with one and only one functionality, and you can also use it to print to `System.err` or into any other "consumer of strings".

Comment: +1 for mentioning the hidden `Locale`-dependencies. I would suggest using a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) instead of a `StringBuilder`, though.

Comment: @Hulk Initially, I sketched a solution using streams and `Collectors.joining(", ")`, but there will still be the `[...]` to add. In the end, the presence of streams does not imply that they are always preferable over loops. This implementation is analogous to `Arrays#toString`, so it should be OK...

Comment: There is also the 3-args version of [Collectors.joining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-). But I did not suggest using Streams here - just using `StringJoiner` directly, which is designed for exactly this use-case.

Comment: @Hulk The 3-args-version is handy. But in any case, this collector has to be "fed" with something, and I think the only way to succinctly do this is via a stream. Maybe I'll have another look and extend the answer, but I don't see an immediate benefit.

Comment: What I meant was just `StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ", "[", "]"); for (double d : array){sj.add(String.format(locale, format, d));} return sj.toString();`

Comment: @Hulk I see. On one hand, it mainly just wraps the `StringBuilder`, but makes the `i>0` check unnecessary, so could be a reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate your array and use decimalFormat update your decimal array.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
double[] ary = {12.4324324, 14.5432, 58.3412};
int i =0;
for (double d : ary) {
     ary[i] = Double.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(d));
     i++;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ary));
```

output of above program.

```
[12.43, 14.54, 58.34]
```